# How to show top banner on product list page

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to display top banner on each category page dynamically. This banner will span whole container. I am using 2columns-left layout. So banner will have 1column layout and list page content will have 2columns-left layout.

I tried following -

```
<catalog_category_default translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Category (Non-Anchor)</label>
        <reference name="category.banner.info">
              <block type="cms/block" name="mystaticblock" >
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>6</block_id></action>
        </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content"> ...
```

on Block 6 i would call phtml file and show banner dynamically. But i dont  think this method will show 1 column layout for banner.

What would be the optimum way to add the banner on product list page?

Comment: Can you tell us what's happening? I don't think your block will be displayed anyway, you need to have it inside the `<reference name="left">` node AFAIK.

Comment: Yes, its not displaying. what would be other solution?

Comment: You have to create a new layout refrence and call to it as per your need

Comment: Refer this tutorial http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-reference-structural-block/